# How to make sure you have enabled Firestore on the Firebase console?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

Now I am developing a project using React Native.
In this project, I use firebaseSDK.

But when I try to login, this error raise up.

```
 ERROR  [Error: [firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.]
 ERROR  The above error occurred in task login
```

I try to find solution on Google, but I can't find solution suitable for me.
I want to make sure I have enabled Firestore on the Firebase console.
How to do that?

Comment: how to backoff?

Comment: After making Firestore you have redownload google services.json file in Firebase.

Comment: backoff means you try to access the firestore in a loop until it succeeds but each time it fails you wait for a longer period of time between tries, often simply 2x as much as you waited before (exponential backoff). And once your wait time reaches a certain maximum (maybe a few minutes) you stay at that maximum because waiting for days isn't a viable strategy in most scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, zapl. I understand that backoff mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your firebase project in [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and make sure you have setup your firestore database in there

Go to `Build > Firestore Database`

and if your screen look like this

[image]

then you need to setup your database by clicking `Create Database` button and completing setup

Comment: I have already created Firestore Database.
But it doesn't work. Maybe what do I have to do when I create Firestore Database?